# Sitecore content tree load really slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I have an issue in one of the legacy sitecore solutions, where an item node takes REALLY long time to load (about 5 mins). This is obviously not a good thing, so I looked into how its setup. Its basically a dictionary item node, its setup something like this:

```
Sitecore 
- Content 
----Definitions 
------ A 
-------- def 1 
-------- def 2 
-------- def 3 
------ B 
------ C 
------ D
```

So apparently they did try to make it so that the items were broken up into separate folders. Under each letter, there is about 200-250 items. I can understand if the expand of each letter takes a long time, but in this case, the slowdown is when you click on 'Definitions'. I can only assume it is trying to load all children and sub children.

Is there any way to stop this so that only one level is opened? I can possibly try to group the sub-tree to be more granular and make a deeper tree, but I'm thinking it won't help in this case, because I'm not even trying to open an node that has too many items (Definitions node only has 26 children - 1 for each letter).

After the first load, the caching helps, but people are already ticked off at the first load.

Any ideas how I can improve the performance of this?

Answer (score 6):

See **ContentEditor.CheckHasChildrenOnTreeNodes** setting in Web.config file. Turning it off may increase performance in your case.

Comment: Good answer, we found ourselves having a big performance increase when turning this (hidden) feature off.